# Getting errors while installing google chrome in ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome

I am something new to ubuntu. I try to install google chrome on ubuntu 64 bit. Now i'm getting error while installing it.
Errors while installing it with ubuntu software centre with google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb.

```
google-chrome-stable:i386: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed
                       Depends: libudev0 (>= 147) but 175-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
                       Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.3-2build1 is installed
                       Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:4.0.1) but 1:5.0-4ubuntu4 is installed
                       Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3.dfsg) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 is installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for this.
Just write

> apt-get upgrade

After completion of this upgrade just restart your system.
After restart google chrome with debian file sucessfully installed.